# Capture Run Time Errors Java

Tags: java, exception, logging, runtime-error

I am sure this must have been asked earlier, but I couldn't search the post.

I want to capture run time errors generated by thread with native java libraries, what methods can I use to do same ?

Here's an example of error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\CR2\Bwac\Database\BWC_EJournal.mdb (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
    at CopyEJ.CopyEJ.main(CopyEJ.java:91)
```

I want to log this error in file to be reviewed later

Comment: Do you enclose potential exception throwing code under `try-catch` and log errors in `catch` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just catch the exception! My guess is that currently your `main` method is declared to throw `Exception`, and you're not catching anything... so the exception is just propagating out of `main`. Just catch the exception:

```
try {
    // Do some operations which might throw an exception
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // Handle the exception however you want, e.g. logging.
    // You may want to rethrow the exception afterwards...
}
```

See the [exceptions part of the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) for more information about exceptions.

The fact that the exception came up in native code is irrelevant here - it's propagated in a perfectly normal way.

Comment: Better explanation than my answer. Beaten by Jon Skeet again :) Do you ever sleep?

Comment: what is the efficient way to implement this because I am using file.io.* at various levels of code .. I would end up having a block at every statement, similarly there is sql exception and parsing exception as well

Comment: @user2385057: Typically you would only catch the exception at a reasonably high level - you usually *don't* want to just log it and continue. I have relatively few try/catch blocks - but far more methods that declare they can throw exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Thread class has 'uncaught exception handler' - see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29. It allows you to delegate exception handling to somewhere outside of your thread, so you don't need to put try-catch in your run() method implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch errors with  the `try block`.

Example

```
try {
    // some i/o function
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // catch the error , you can log these
    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IOException e) {
    // catch the error , you can log these
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[Java Tutorials- Lesson: Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Answer (score 1):

its good practices use `try` `catch` and `finally`

```
try {
     //Your code goes here    

 } catch (Exception e) {
    //handle exceptions over here
} finally{
   //close your open connections
}
```